# Formating xtable based on condition with lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, xtable

I want to color cells in a Latex table created with `xtable`. 
I have a data frame that looks like:

```
a <- data.frame(a=c(seq(1:100)),b=c(seq(1:100)),b=c(seq(1:100)))
```

Now I want every cell colored individually based on its value. I created the following function to achieve this:

```
formatting<-function(x){ifelse(x<50,paste("\\cellcolor{red}{",x,"}"),x)
                         ifelse(x>=50&x<=80,paste("\\cellcolor{yellow}{",x,"}"),x)
                         ifelse(x>=80,paste("\\cellcolor{green}{",x,"}"),x)
}
```

However, applying `lapply` on this data frame with my function only executes the last line of the function (coloration in green)

```
a <- data.frame(lapply(a, FUN=formatting))
```

Basically I want values <50 to occure in red (`\\cellcolor{red}{",x,"}")`, values between 50-80 in yellow (`\\cellcolor{yellow}{",x,"}")`, and values above 80 in green (`\\cellcolor{green}{",x,"}")`

What is wrong in my function? I also noted that if I would create a function for every color individually I run into a warning saying:

```
red<-function(x){ifelse(x<50,paste("\\cellcolor{red}{",x,"}"),x)}            
yellow<-function(x){ifelse(x>=50&x<=80,paste("\\cellcolor{yellow}{",x,"}"),x)}
green<-function(x){ifelse(x>=80,paste("\\cellcolor{green}{",x,"}"),x)}

a <- data.frame(lapply(a, FUN=red))
a <- data.frame(lapply(a, FUN=yellow))
a <- data.frame(lapply(a, FUN=green))

Warning message:
1: In Ops.factor(x, 50) : >= not meaningful for factors
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I played a bit with the following code :

```
resistant<-function(x){ifelse((x>=0&x<50),paste("\\cellcolor{red}{",x,"}"),x)}
intermediate<-function(x){ifelse((x>=50&x<80),paste("\\cellcolor{yellow}{",x,"}"),x)}
susceptible<-function(x){ifelse((x>=80&x<=100),paste("\\cellcolor{green}{",x,"}"),x)}
a<-as.data.frame(apply(a,2, FUN=resistant))
a<-as.data.frame(apply(a,2, FUN=intermediate))
a<-as.data.frame(apply(a,2, FUN=susceptible))
```

However, it seems that only the last line is not executed properly. Why?

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to solve the problem myself. The solution that worked for me was using a nested `ifelse` function:

```
func<-function(x){ifelse(x<50,paste("\\cellcolor{red}{",x,"}"),
                          ifelse(x>=50&x<80,paste("\\cellcolor{yellow}{",x,"}"),paste("\\cellcolor{green}{",x,"}")))}
```

and apply this:

```
a<-as.data.frame(apply(a,2, FUN=func))
```

That did the job :)